# How to publish TypeScript 2 package with custom typings

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, yarnpkg

I have a TS project that is published to a private npm registry to be used by other in-house projects (probably all TS as well). This project has a mix of publicly available declaration files (`node_moduels/@types`) and custom declarations.

What is the correct way to setup the `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` so the contents of the custom `d.ts` files are available to other projects importing this one?

The project is fairly simple, but my current solution only publishes the built `index.js` and `index.d.ts` to the registry so when imported by other projects `tsc` complains about the missing types.

```
Project
├── index.ts
├── typings
│   ├── moduleA.d.ts
│   └── moduleB.d.ts
├── package.json
└── ...
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "ES7"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "rootDir": "./",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "include": [
    "index.ts",
    "typings/**/*"
  ]
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "main": "index.js",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": ...
  },
  "files": [
    "index.js",
    "index.d.ts"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/...": "1.0.0",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Also, is it better to have `"declaration": true` and include `index.d.ts` in the list of `files` (like I have already), or should I just include `index.ts` in the list of `files`?